How to Install NetLogo v 6.4.0 Mathematica Link?
EnteringNLStart[ "/Applications/NetLogo 6.4.0/" ]after installing netlogo.m as/Users/my_name/Library/Mathematica/Applications/NetLogo.wl returns the message

NetLogo could not be found in: /Applications/NetLogo 6.4.0/

I follow instructions in NetLogo 6.4.0 to install netlogo.m as
/Users/my_name/Library/Mathematica/Applications/NetLogo.wl
The next instruction for Mathematica is << NetLogo` which executes without error.
The next instruction for Mathematica isNLStart[ "/Applications/NetLogo 6.4.0/" ]
which returns the message above.
I am running macOS Sonoma 14.5 and Mathematica 14.0.0.0.
I see previous threads concerning the same problem, but dating back to NetLogo 6.0.1 and 6.1.0. I see reported a fix for this version of NetLogo and a report thatNLStart[ "/Applications/NetLogo 6.2.0/" ] worked.  The same problem I have is reported forNLStart[ "/Applications/NetLogo 6.3.0/" ] at https://groups.google.com/g/netlogo-devel/c/2k1XgXcO4z0 with no replies to that post.
I cannot find anything more recent. Any assistance?

OK. I started over with the install. I reached NLStart["/Applications/NetLogo 6.4.0/"] and this time the error message read NLStart::nopath: NetLogo cannot be started without a valid NetLogo 6.2 path.
I looked at NetLogo.m searching for an occurrence of 6.2 that I could change to 6.4, but all occurrences of 6.2 seemed to appear only in comments or usage remarks.
So I gave up and downloaded NetLogo 6.2.2, after which NLStart[ ] command has launched NetLogo!
